# Run Docker commands in Jenkins Shell

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to run docker commands in Jenkins Shell

The command shell that I am trying is

```
# optional: record current versions of docker apps with each build
docker -v && docker-compose -v && docker-machine -v

# set-up: clean up any previous machine failures
docker-machine stop test || echo "nothing to stop" && \
docker-machine rm test   || echo "nothing to remove"

# use docker-machine to create and configure 'test' environment
# add a -D (debug) if having issues
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox test
eval "$(docker-machine env test)"

# use docker-compose to pull and build new images and containers
docker-compose -p jenkins up -d

# optional: list machines, images, and containers
docker-machine ls && docker images && docker ps -a

# wait for containers to fully start before tests fire up
sleep 30

# test services
sh tests.sh $(docker-machine ip test)

# tear down: stop and remove 'test' environment
#docker-machine stop test && docker-machine rm test
```

Does anyone know how to set up Jenkins to run docker commands (`docker`, `docker-compose` and `docker-machine`)?

**UPDATE(Error Message)**

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Virtual-Vehicles_Docker_Machine/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/garystafford/virtual-vehicles-docker.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/garystafford/virtual-vehicles-docker.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/garystafford/virtual-vehicles-docker.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 433683c8b9da5272b9f98c9a9653aac5bfb8c0b5 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 433683c8b9da5272b9f98c9a9653aac5bfb8c0b5
 > git rev-list 433683c8b9da5272b9f98c9a9653aac5bfb8c0b5 # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5615310598120649485.sh
+ docker -v
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5615310598120649485.sh: line 3: docker: command not found
+ docker-machine stop test
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5615310598120649485.sh: line 6: docker-machine: command not found
+ echo 'nothing to stop'
nothing to stop
+ docker-machine rm test
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5615310598120649485.sh: line 7: docker-machine: command not found
+ echo 'nothing to remove'
nothing to remove
+ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox test
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson5615310598120649485.sh: line 11: docker-machine: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Command **docker version**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 22:37:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 22:37:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Command **docker-compose -v**

```
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
```

Command **docker-machine -v**

```
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

Comment: Is docker already installed on the machine Jenkins is installed on?  Have you looked at Jenkin's plugins for docker already?  What particular issues have you encountered?

Comment: I don't see any error messages here.

Comment: hi @larsks , I have added the error message

Comment: You are getting `command not found` errors.  Your system doesn't have Docker installed.

Comment: @larsks but I only have one machine,OS X Yosemite, thas has Jenkins installed and docker, is in a Host Machine(Virtual Box),  maybe the problem is that Jenkins is no connect to the Host Machine, How can I set up my Jenkins to conect with Docker through CLI?

Comment: please update question with environment, where is Jenkins (OS X or Virtualbox),docker (I guess it is docker toolbox),do you know Jenkins master/slave ? Need to know where the shell is executed.